# htaccess to protect download folder

Tags: .htaccess

I added the following lines in the htaccess file in my **download** directory -

```
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Now I want to rewrite all URL from,

```
https://example.com/download/myfile.pdf 
to 
https://example.com/get-file.php?directory=download&request=myfile.pdf
```

Following is my **htaccess file in web root** -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L] 

RewriteRule    ^download/([A-Za-z0-9-.]*+)/?$    get-file.php?directory=download&request=$1   [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /invalid-page-name

# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

This does not work. Please can anyone tell me where I am making mistake? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change

```
order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

to

```
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```